# Loading json after a button click

Tags: php, javascript, json, html

I want to load a json file after a user clicks on a button, not sure how to do that.

If I load the file directly it will load using the following.

```
 <script src="data.json" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But I want the user to click a button before it loads instead of loading when the page is accessed.

Thanks

Comment: Using the following what?

Comment: sorry just updated it, first time using the site. @dbf

Comment: @user2278544, was I able to help in my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: use AJAX.  It will load anything you want via Javascript which you can assign timings to.  In this example we attach a `click` event to `#myButton` and when the event fires, we run a `getJSON()` call to the URL and handle the data accordingly.

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">Button</button>
```

**Javascript (jQuery in my example)**

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        //Handle my response
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

If you want an example not using jQuery then [Google "Javascript AJAX"](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20getjson&aq=f&oq=jquery%20get&aqs=chrome.0.59j57j5j59j60l2.1949j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#sclient=psy-ab&q=Javascript%20AJAX&oq=Javascript%20AJAX&gs_l=serp.3..0l4.64521.67231.0.67390.17.9.1.7.7.0.72.425.9.9.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.P97AK_OQO5E&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45175338,d.eWU&fp=6c3dfd5e76c68c34&biw=1335&bih=727).

Comment: yes thank you. i actually needed getscript not getjson because i realised data.json was not correct json format but correct javascript format. thank you for your help.

Comment: @cereallarceny from you answer . when it have condition that need serialize a from 1st before getting the alert data, just add `$("#atextboxdata").serialize();` before the code `$.getJSON` right?